# How to make pattern of REST controllers

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm writing my first spring application, and would like to get experience to make an optimal and attractive code on spring.
I've some restcontrollers which have the big part of similar code

```
   @RequestMapping(path = "/1154",
                method = RequestMethod.POST,
                headers = {"Content-Type=application/json"},
                consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE,
                produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)

        public CreateUserResp processRequest(@RequestBody @Valid CreateUserReq request, BindingResult bindingResult) {

            CreateUserResp response = new CreateUserResp();

            if (bindingResult.hasErrors()){

                response.setResultCode(102); // Validation error
                response.setErrMsg("Wrong " + bindingResult.getFieldError().getDefaultMessage() + " value.");

            } else {
                   // main service
                   request = UserService.doSomething();

            }
            return response;
        }

 @RequestMapping(path = "/1155",
                method = RequestMethod.POST,
                headers = {"Content-Type=application/json"},
                consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE,
                produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)

        public ChangeUserResp processRequest(@RequestBody @Valid ChangeUserReq request, BindingResult bindingResult) {

            ChangeUserResp response = new ChangeUserResp();

            if (bindingResult.hasErrors()){

                response.setResultCode(102); // Validation error
                response.setErrMsg("Wrong " + bindingResult.getFieldError().getDefaultMessage() + " value.");

            } else {
                   // main service
                   request = ChangeService.doSomething();

            }
            return response;
        }

 @RequestMapping(path = "/1156",
                method = RequestMethod.POST,
                headers = {"Content-Type=application/json"},
                consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE,
                produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)

        public AddUserResp processRequest(@RequestBody @Valid AddUserReq request, BindingResult bindingResult) {

            AddUserResp response = new AddUserResp();

            if (bindingResult.hasErrors()){

                response.setResultCode(102); // Validation error
                response.setErrMsg("Wrong " + bindingResult.getFieldError().getDefaultMessage() + " value.");

            } else {
                   // main service
                   request = AddService.doSomething();

            }
            return response;
        }

 @RequestMapping(path = "/1157",
                method = RequestMethod.POST,
                headers = {"Content-Type=application/json"},
                consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE,
                produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)

        public ModifyUserResp processRequest(@RequestBody @Valid ModifyUserReq request, BindingResult bindingResult) {

            ModifyUserResp response = new ModifyUserResp();

            if (bindingResult.hasErrors()){

                response.setResultCode(102); // Validation error
                response.setErrMsg("Wrong " + bindingResult.getFieldError().getDefaultMessage() + " value.");

            } else {
                   // main service
                   request = ModifyService.doSomething();

            }
            return response;
        }
```

etc ....

The only differences in (path, @RequestBody and Responce objects, and called  service ). So, I'll have 10-12 controllers like this one. Is it the way to make this code more optimal and not to write this repeatable blocks of code 10 times (spring methods or may be using generic class or methods). It's just example, not real code. Thx

Especial thanks to people who are very busy to answer but have time to put minus.

Comment: A watcher to handle the errors of all your request methods?

Comment: yes, just the same structure I only change pojo object for incoming json objects for make validation. And incoming request depends on controller path. Responce depends on request object

Comment: Put all the commen stuff on the class (for the `@RequestMapping`) only define the differences on the methods `@RequestMapping`. Next to that the methods are diffrent, the fact that something looks the sme doesn't make them the same. If you can generify things at this level you are doing something wrong imho...

Answer (score 0):

I have something quite similar in my application.

For example this is how my editProfile method from the User controller looks like:

```
@PostMapping(value = EDIT_CONTACT_INFO)
public ResponseEntity<?> editContactInfo(
        @Autowired HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
        @RequestBody @Valid ContactInfoDTO.Req requestBody,
        BindingResult bindingResult
)
{
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors())
        // 400 - BAD REQUEST
        return ErrorsDTO.from(bindingResult).responseEntity();

    String userName = ControllerUtils.getUserName(httpServletRequest);
    User user =  userService.findByUserName(userName);
    ContactInfo contactInfo = modelMapper.map(requestBody, ContactInfo.class);

    if (!userService.editContactInfo(user, contactInfo))
        // 500 - INTERNAL SERVER ERROR
        return ErrorsDTO.from(INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).responseEntity();

    // 200 - OK
    return ResponseEntity.ok(null);
}
```

The majority of my API looks quite similar to yours. I've just written my custom mechanism to report errors, and I use a `ResponseEntity` instance to return data.

Also I have a library to pass data from DTOs to my Model and back (it's called ModelMapper).

Comment: Thx, but i should change ContactInfoDTO.Req in different controllers

Answer (score 0):

edit: it looks like this blogpost covers your question:
http://blog.codeleak.pl/2013/09/request-body-validation-in-spring-mvc-3.2.html

---

If you really want to get down and dirty, you *could* write an interceptor, with a pointcut on a new annotation `ValidateBinding` and an argument of BindingResult. It would probably look something like:

```
@Around("@annotation(ValidateBinding) && execution(* *(..)) && args(bindingResult)
public Object handleInvalidBindings(ProceedingJoinPoint p, BindingResult bindingResult) {

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()){
        GenericResponse response = createTypedResponse(p);
        response.setResultCode(102); // Validation error
        response.setErrMsg("Wrong " + bindingResult.getFieldError().getDefaultMessage() + " value.");
        return response;
    } 
    return pjp.proceed();
}

private GenericResponse createTypedResponse(ProceedingJoinPoint p) {
    MethodSignature signature = (MethodSignature) p.getSignature();
    Method method = signature.getMethod();
    Class responseClass = method.getReturnType();
    if(!GenericResponse.class.isAssignableFrom(responseClass)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Could not create proper response class - it should implement the GenericResponse interface");
    return (GenericResponse) responseClass.newInstance();
}
```

But I'm not guaranteeing the expression or the code works. This is more a rough guess on how it could look.

To do this, you'd need an interface `GenericResponse` which is implemented by your responseclasses, and has a setResultCode and setErrMsg.

Comment: Thx but may be I'm didn't explained clearly my question (or I didn't understand your answer ) . I've changed code in question.  I'm try to find a way how to make a pattern of the repeatable code for making  it more compactable.

Comment: If you want to use generic code, all your responses should be 'generic' as well... Or at least, the errorhandling part. And since you do want a specific response, hence the code to determine what sort of response is necessary. Come to think about it, you can probably get all that from reflection of the method being called, so that should clean up the code a bit. But it's reflection and workarounds, so it's a bit dirty...
As others have said, your current code is *not* generic, as it uses a specific response, which makes it differ from all other code.